# Included file changing url

Tags: php, include, href

I have searched the internet for a couple of hours now but i cant find the answer to my question.

How can i switch between url with included php file?

My include file is the following:

```
<li class="werkgeversNavbar">
    <a href=<?php echo '"'.'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/dritjob/werkgevers.php"'?>>Voor werkgevers </a>
    <a href=<?php echo '"'.'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/dritjob/index.php"'?>>Voor werkzoekende </a>
</li>
```

For instance when i am on my 'index.php' i want the first link to be shown, and when i click on that link i want the 'werkgevers.php' to change into 'index.php'.

How can this be achieved? 
Sorry for my bad english any replay would be great, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a quick fix for your problem, but you can do more complicated if you've get the point:

```
<li class="werkgeversNavbar">
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.php') {
        ?>
        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/dritjob/werkgevers.php">">Voor werkgevers </a>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/dritjob/index.php">Voor werk zoekende </a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your replay. i have changed the code and i get an error
'Notice: Undefined variable: _SEVER in C:\xampp\htdocs\dritjob\core\includes\header.php on line 146'
i will search the problem my self thanks anyway :)

Comment: Edited the code. That should be `SERVER` not `SEVER`. There was a missing `R`

Comment: That fixed the error, but the link only shows the second href 'dritjob/index.php'
On both the page's

Comment: I fixed it by changing the 
`if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.php') {`
INTO
`if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/dritjob/index.php') {`

Thanks for your help!